# Prerequisites for Random Graph Theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, random-graphs

I would dearly love to know the prerequisites for self-studying Random Graph Theory and Percolation Theory in Probability.

My knowledge currently involves:

- Basic probability concepts: the axioms, random variables, distributions.
- Limit theorems in probability
- Random Walk

Are these enough or do I need anything extra? It would be great if you kindly pointwise write down ALL the prerequisites, along with a nice book on Random Graphs and Percolation Theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 3 points you listed would satisfy the prerequisites.

Comment: I think a bit of graph theory would be necessary too, eh?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I currently have no knowledge about Graph Theory, so I need to study it first, right?

Comment: @LandonCarter I would say that the amount of graph theory that you would need to know before looking into random graphs is pretty minimal and could be picked up along the way. I had very little graph theory before studying random graphs and did not find the books listed below to require much prior graph knowledge. For books, I suggest Random Graphs by Janson, Łuczak and Rucinski or Random Graphs by Bollobás.

Comment: Thank you very much D Poole. Are you are Probabilist?

Comment: @D Poole Sorry for bringing up an old topic but you were right: I studied Random Graph Theory from Hofstad's notes and found very little mention of actual graph theory. The concept was used and almost entirely things happened through Branching Processes.